# Escaping characters before insert into database

Tags: php

I want to convert some characters before inserting them into database for example

Ž, Ć

I get data from post, and sanitize it on this whay

```
$ime =  (string) htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['txtIme']), ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8', true);
```

In some reason I get still Ž, Š into my database

Comment: Don't, you'll get into a horrible mess eventually : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Why do you want them encoded ? Your database hasn't the correct character set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

> all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities

If you look at http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Ž, Ć don't have HTML character entity equivalents.  Š does.  Which is why

```
<?php
     $string = 'In some reason I get still Ž, Š, Ć into my database';
     echo htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8', true);
?>
```

Produces:

```
$ php utf.php
In some reason I get still Ž, &Scaron;, Ć into my database
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to convert them to, `mysql_set_charset()` might the function you need to use. Using UTF-8 encoding, you can store most non-Standard characters, too.

However you should be careful with the mysql Extension, as it is deprecated. You should take a look at `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.